# how to configure jetty to use log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

How do I configure jetty to use use log4j?  I'm already using log4j in my application, while jetty logs to stderr...

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class Test {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        logger.info("Started.");

        Server server = new Server();

        Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        connector.setPort(8080);       

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletHome()), "/");                       

        // disable jettys default logger
        //org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(null);

        server.addConnector(connector);
        server.setHandler(context);

        logger.debug("Starting jetty.");
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Ooops.");
        }

        logger.info("Finished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @musiKk.  I added slf4j-api.jar slf4j-log4j.jar to my classpath and it did indeed get wired automatically.

It might be worth noting that jetty is very noisy when debug logging is enabled in log4j, so I added this to log4j.properties to reduce the noise:

    `log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO`

Comment: Yes, that's quite common. Debug levels usually are very verbose and sometimes it makes sense to selectively activate or deactivate packages to get a more sensible output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jetty uses [slf4j for logging](http://www.slf4j.org). slf4j allows a unified logging API to connect to any supported logging framework. Of course log4j is supported too. All you have to do is put both the slf4j API and slf4j-log4j connector to your classpath. It should get wired automatically.